# Does stub file in client side repeat (simulate) all actions that ocurrs in server side

Tags: java, rmi, stub

Does stub file in client side repeat (simulate) all processes that ocurrs in server side. Please, explain what is the role of stub in RMI and how does it interact with other files of RMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stub translates the call of a method (for example `String sayHello(String who)`) to a message sent on the network to the RMI server, then waits for the response from the server, translates it to the return type of the method, and then returns. So, the code of a stub, basically, is something like this (this is not real code. It's just for you to get the idea):

```
public String sayHello(String who) {
    byte[] message = translateMethodCallToBytes("sayHello", who);
    byte[] response = sendMessageToServer(message);
    String result = extractReturnValueFromResponse(response);
    return result;
}
```

The skeleton, at server-side, does basically the same thing, but in reverse mode: it listens for messages from clients, translates the messages to method calls, then invokes the actual RMI object and sends the result as a response over the network.

Comment: ok, if so, why do we compile stub file from the java file that contains methods of out web service ?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Your question is about RMI, not web services.

Comment: The stub is specific to the remote interface it is for.